# Notify Users on User Defined Events on Data changes on server

Tags: database, design-patterns, listener, models, observer-pattern

I have a node.js webservice with 10k users.each user can monitor price changes of  1k items(realtime or every second).
my problem started here:
each user can listen 4 event : start/stop/higher/lower for each item.
when event fired i need to send sms or email to user.
which design pattern or database model i need to implement this ?
how to implement it? any book or reference?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you have an object which must notify subscribers about changes - you have to use `Observer`.

 If you have relationships many to many you can use `Mediator` - pattern which encapsulates how a set of objects interact.

But in your case (10k users & 1k items) - you have to have good abstration layer... Split your items and users into groups and use these groups for design pattern...